# What is the best way to prevent a user from starting an app while uninstall

Tags: c#, .net, uninstallation

I am developing a C# windows service + UI application.

I have a problem that if during the uninstall process the user is trying to launch the UI then the uninstall gets corrupted and stuck (because the ui holds handles to some files and prevents them from getting deleted).

What is the best way to handle this situation? I thought that maybe I should strict the access to the .exe when I am starting the uninstall process, so the user won't be able to launch it.

But I was wondering if there is a BKM of how to do that

**EDIT**

The application is already installed on customers' machines, So I can't make any changes to the application itself.

I have an upgrade installer that can do stuff as part of the uninstallation process. The upgrade installer first uninstall the application and then reinstall it. I can add code only to the upgrade installer so I can't use a mutex for example.
Thanks!

Comment: Use a global mutex identifier, and when it is not new, exit the application. Restricting the .exe is some weird hack.

Comment: _"What is the best way to handle this situation?"_ - make the installer throw a warning that files to be removed are in use.

Comment: Please tell us more about "the uninstall". Is it home-brewed? Dealing with locked/in-use files is a well-worn path and the uninstall process should deal with this problem correctly.

Comment: @spender - Best Known Method

Answer (score 0):

You can use named mutex, it is windows core object and two processes can check if it is already registered or not.

While uninstalling just create a named mutex, and check if it exists on process start

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f55ddskf.aspx) is how to create named mutex

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194641.aspx) is how to check if it exists

Answer (score 0):

How about killing the process in the Uninstall?

```
    public static bool KillProcess(string yourProcessName)
{
    foreach (Process clsProcess in Process.GetProcesses())
    {
        if (Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id == clsProcess.Id)
            continue;
        if (clsProcess.ProcessName.Contains(name))
        {
            clsProcess.Kill();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```